Maximum call stack size exceeded - Formik
I am using formik to validate the inputs on my react native application.. I have used the validationSchema to define the validation of the inputs.
So, whenever I am arriving to the screen that contains with formik validation crashes suddenly and showing the error log
Please refer the screenshots and also it saying Cannot read property "Formik" of undefined. But, I assure the package has been installed in the project
  const validationSchema = {
    first_name: yup.string().required('First name is required') 
  };
            <Formik
            initialValues={{first_name: 'ROoabn'}}
            validationSchema={yup.object().shape(validationSchema)}
            onSubmit={onSaveChanges}>
            {({handleChange, handleBlur, values, errors, touched}) => (
              <Input
                id="first_name"
                label="First Name"
                value={values?.first_name}
                errors={errors.first_name}
                touched={touched.first_name}
                onChange={handleChange('first_name')}
                onBlur={handleBlur('first_name')}
              />
            )}
          </Formik>




Do you define validationSchema outside of your component?

Nope, I have defined inside the component

Calling A Function
You can call a function by adding brackets () right after the function signature.
The Issue
The Issue is that you are calling the handleChange and handleBlur function inside the rendering code. Every time the screen is rendered your handle change function is called. Which triggers another re-render due to state change. Which again will trigger another handleChange call on render making the renders infinite giving the subsequent error.
        <Formik
            initialValues={{first_name: 'ROoabn'}}
            validationSchema={yup.object().shape(validationSchema)}
            onSubmit={onSaveChanges}>
            {({handleChange, handleBlur, values, errors, touched}) => (
              <Input
                id="first_name"
                label="First Name"
                value={values?.first_name}
                errors={errors.first_name}
                touched={touched.first_name}
                onChange={handleChange('first_name')} // OVER HERE
                onBlur={handleBlur('first_name')} // OVER HERE
              />
            )}
          </Formik>

Solution
The solution is simple, you can do () => handleChange('firstName') or you can give handleChange as it is, as formik will handle the state updates for you

Still the issue exisit..

Can you share your code on https://snack.expo.dev/ updating your question

Please have a look https://snack.expo.dev/2Qu-dSNSHCusT0CtDKODq

It is preferable that you give only the code where the issue is happening (minimum reproducible example) so that it will be easier to fix. Please edit the snack to remove everything except the piece of code giving issue and all it's related dependencies.

I have updated the snack, Please check https://snack.expo.dev/0vdBy7eNK3sFjT_c1Los3
